# Why are there dummy modules in sys.modules?

Tags: python, import

Importing the standard "logging" module pollutes sys.modules with a bunch of dummy entries:

```
Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Dec 23 2008, 15:10:54) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>>> import sys
>>> import logging
>>> sorted(x for x in sys.modules.keys() if 'log' in x)
['logging', 'logging.atexit', 'logging.cStringIO', 'logging.codecs', 
'logging.os', 'logging.string', 'logging.sys', 'logging.thread', 
'logging.threading', 'logging.time', 'logging.traceback', 'logging.types']

# and perhaps even more surprising:
>>> import traceback
>>> traceback is sys.modules['logging.traceback']
False
>>> sys.modules['logging.traceback'] is None
True
```

So importing this package puts extra names into sys.modules, except that they are not modules, just references to None.  Other modules (e.g. xml.dom and encodings) have this issue as well.  Why?

**Edit:** Building on bobince's answer, there are pages describing [the origin](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/packages/) (see section "Dummy Entries in sys.modules") and [future](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#relative-imports-and-indirection-entries-in-sys-modules) of the feature.

Comment: Good link... I hadn't actually spotted this being documented anywhere before. Evidently for some reason I hadn't searched for the obvious title “The Knights Who Say Neeeow ... Wum ... Ping”. Ah, Python...

Comment: I was going to post an exact duplicate - my second today :P

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`None` values in `sys.modules` are cached failures of relative lookups.

So when you're in package `foo` and you `import sys`, Python looks first for a `foo.sys` module, and if that fails goes to the top-level `sys` module. To avoid having to check the filesystem for `foo/sys.py` again on further relative imports, it stores `None` in the `sys.modules` to flag that the module didn't exist and a subsequent import shouldn't look there again, but go straight to the loaded `sys`.

This is a cPython implementation detail you can't usefully rely on, but you will need to know it if you're doing nasty magic import/reload hacking.

It happens to all packages, not just `logging`. For example, `import xml.dom` and see `xml.dom.xml` in the module list as it tries to import `xml` from inside `xml.dom`.

As Python moves towards absolute import this ugliness will happen less.

Comment: Thanks! I added links in my question to background in, and referenced by, http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328

Comment: If it "happens to all packages", why have I never seen this with my own stuff?  I'd expect to see "mymodule.sys", "mymodule.os" and so forth with dozens and dozens of such dummy modules around but only see it with a few like xml.dom, logging, and encodings (as D.Shawley mentions).

Comment: It happens to my packages. But only packages, not simple modules.

Comment: Strange.  I'm dead certain I've frequently checked sys.modules in the past for various debugging purposes, without noticing dozens of stdlib modules referenced in sys.modules as dummy modules under my subpackages.  Yet there they are, with things like 'xxx.xxx.sys' showing up 16 times, for example.