# how to reload updated function in python console in pycharm

Tags: python, console, pycharm

first I define a function c1() in a file called CT.py as below

```
def c1():
    result = 1
    return result
```

so now if I type the following code in python console

```
from CT import c1
```

then run c1(), it will give a value of 1

however, if now I change CT.py as below (change declaration of c1) and save it

```
def c1():
    result = 100
    return result
```

now if I type the following code in python console

```
from CT import c1
```

and run c1(), why do I still get a value of 1?

Why won't it import the new c1 function whose resulting value should be 100?

To get the new c1 function, it seems that I have to close the python console (or pycharm) and run the code again.

Is there a way to reload the function without rerun the python console in pycharm?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reloading a function within a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48038180/reloading-a-function-within-a-module)

Answer (score 0):

You can reload using this code:

```
reload(c1)
from CT import c1
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48038180/reloading-a-function-within-a-module) may help.

[Documentation](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/reload.html)

Comment: You should flag duplicates, not restate the answer

Comment: Thanks, dd23. What if I have updated many functions in CT.py? I need to type reload for each of them? i.e reload(c1) reload(c2) ... reload(cN)... Are there a way to do this in batch?