# Changes made to variable not reflected in console

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import

Code speaks better:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones(shape=(4, 2))
def func():
    for i in a:
        print(i)
```

**Run:**

```
In[3]: func()
[1. 1.]
[1. 1.]
[1. 1.]
[1. 1.]
In[4]: a = np.zeros(shape=(4, 2))
In[5]: func()
[1. 1.]
[1. 1.]
[1. 1.]
[1. 1.]
```

Notice that I changed (a). But, when I run the function again, no changes!!
Details: latest version of **Pycharm**. Configs > Execution: Run with Python console.

Comment: Originally, this started as a massive neural net with modular design. Following 3 days of debugging, I reduced it to that.

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51239527/how-to-reload-updated-function-in-python-console-in-pycharm

Comment: @XaviMartínez No, I'm not updating the function. But yes, solve my problem, I just need to define the same function again and it works! But why is that given that the function did not change. It was (a) who changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Pycharm. But I think I know why.

When you Run with Python console, it should have `from your-source-file import *` in background.

When you rebind `a` to new object in console, the func will still use `the a` in your-source-file, not `the a` in console.

You can have a try by explicitly `from your-source-file import *` and take the rest of actions to verify it. I have checked it on my computer by myself.

If you want understand why, you can read [4. Execution model: resolution-of-names — Python 3.7.3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names), and make sure you understand this:

> When a name is used in a code block, it is resolved using the nearest enclosing scope. The set of all such scopes visible to a code block is called the block’s environment.

My try in ipython:

```
In [2]: from test import *

In [3]: func()
[1. 1.]
[1. 1.]
[1. 1.]
[1. 1.]

In [4]: a = np.zeros(shape=(4, 2))

In [5]: func()
[1. 1.]
[1. 1.]
[1. 1.]
[1. 1.]

In [6]: def func():
   ...:     for i in a:
   ...:         print(i)
   ...:

In [7]: func()
[0. 0.]
[0. 0.]
[0. 0.]
[0. 0.]
```

and

```
In [1]: from auto_audit_backend.test_np import *

In [2]: func()
[1. 1.]
[1. 1.]
[1. 1.]
[1. 1.]

In [3]: a[0][0] = 666

In [4]: func()
[666.   1.]
[1. 1.]
[1. 1.]
[1. 1.]

In [5]: a = np.zeros(shape=(4, 2))

In [6]: func()
[666.   1.]
[1. 1.]
[1. 1.]
[1. 1.]
```

with your code in test.py file.

Comment: Woah, you are a genius, you regenerated the problem in a different platform. So, you're saying no bugs with Pycharm?

Comment: How do I prevent this from happening? This  is causing me a headache while I'm experimenting with neural nets.

Comment: @AlexDeft Yes, I think no bugs with Pycharm, you can just try in Pycharm console. It is the rule of Python.

Comment: @AlexDeft pass your variable to func, not use global variable, which is a bad 
 habit and would be invalid when you import it from somewhere else.