# Is there any way to change variables or functions defined outer in a function

Tags: python

Assuming that I have `foo.py` like below.
This file is not created by me, so I want neither to modify nor copy this. 
In other words, `foo.py` is in some extra package I installed.

```py
# foo.py

def bar():
  print('This is bar')

def foo():
  print('something')
  bar()
  print('something')
```

Then, I want to implement `foo_as_baz()` behaving as comments.

```py
# baz.py

from foo import foo

def baz():
  print('This is baz')

def foo_as_baz():
"""
This function is expected to behave as below
  print('something')
  baz()
  print('something')
"""  
  pass
```

I tried below one but it does not work since the namescope differs.

```
def foo_as_baz():
  bar = baz # I expect this `baz` affects `bar` function in `foo`
  foo()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changes made to variable not reflected in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56615309/changes-made-to-variable-not-reflected-in-console)

Comment: look at my another answer a few days ago. look different, but same issue in fact.

Comment: The underlying issue is the same as in that question, but I think there's some possible nuance here about mocking and how module attributes work.

Comment: @JoshKarpel I think understand the underlying issue is key. After that, you can do whatever you want by any possible trick.

Comment: @LiuXiMin 
Thanks.
 if `a` shows zeros, this issue is the same as yours.

```
In [5]: a = np.zeros(shape=(4, 2))

In [6]: func()
[666.   1.]
[1. 1.]
[1. 1.]
[1. 1.]
```

Comment: @Hironori Yes, it does. `a` is rebound to zeros, but `func` can not see it unless you redefine a new `func`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record: **don't do the thing below the horizontal rule in normal code**. It's confusing and largely pointless.

If you're doing this kind of thing to test your code, I recommend the standard library [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) package, which provides a systematic way to replace Python objects with fake Python objects for testing purposes.

If you think you have some real non-testing use case, please elaborate...

---

```
# foo.py

def bar():
    print("This is bar")

def foo():
    print("something")
    bar()
    print("something")
```

And then then in another file:

```
import foo


def baz():
    print("This is baz")


def foo_as_baz():
    original = foo.bar  # save a copy of the original bar()

    foo.bar = baz       # make foo.bar point to baz()

    foo.foo()           

    foo.bar = original  # cleanup by restoring bar()


foo_as_baz()
```

The key difference from your attempt is that I did `import foo`, which lets me look into the actual module namespace `foo`. I swap `foo.bar` for `baz`, then call `foo.foo()`, then switch `foo.bar` back to the original `bar` function.

This works because **functions are effectively attributes of modules**. Therefore, we can reassign those attributes as if they were attributes of any other object (because, in Python, everything, including modules, are objects).

Comment: As you said, this is a very dangerous code. Do you think which is better to copy all the `foo` function or your implementation shown in the above? @JoshKarpel

Comment: @Hironori Could you clarify what you mean by "copy all of the `foo` function"?

Comment: When I wrote this, I meant copy all the source of `foo` to another file. But now, I realize that there is another way based on  `new_foo = foo.copy()`. I think this better than the others. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the function itself as an argument to `foo` by slightly modifying how `foo` works

```
def foo(func=bar):
   print('something')
   func()
   print('something')

def foo_as_baz():
   foo(baz)
```

By adding `bar` as the default argument to `foo` you retain the original behaviour

Comment: Yes, but `foo()` has no argument and I do not want to modify `foo`, if possible. I know this question is much odd.

Comment: But `foo` when called without any arguments still exhibits the same behaviour. So what would be the issue?

Comment: @Hironori rebind an object to bar in your file can not affect the bar in `foo`, it is the scope rule of Python.